# How to use the JavaScript API of PhantomJS in a Java Application

Tags: java, javascript, phantomjs, alert, headless-browser

I want to write an application in Java, which should test a website in a headless browser, like for example PhantomJS or zombie.js. PhantomJS scripts are written in JavaScript so how can I use the JavaScript API provided by PhantomJS in my Java application without using Selenium with GhostDriver? Has this something to do with the library Nashorn?

More details with the steps I need to go through:
1. Create a HTTP-Request (for example with: java.net.HttpUrlConnection.) and send it to a Web Server
2. Get the corresponding Response and save the Source in a HTML File
3. Open the HTML File in a FAST headless browser (no HtmlUnit)
4. Verify if an Alert with message xxx appears or not when opening the HTML Response

Does anybody know a solution?
PS: It would be easy if PhantomJs with GhostDriver would support alert handling, but it does not!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test in a headless browser from a Java application, the path of least resistance is to use the Selenium Java driver, with [HtmlUnit](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver).

Nashorn will not provide a JavaScript API to you for PhantomJS; nor will it provide the browser objects like "window" and "document." It will allow you to run JavaScript within your Java program with any "host" (native Java) objects you provide, and create Java objects within JavaScript, so of course you could re-implement the PhantomJS API in Java. But presumably that's not what you want.

Comment: I am using right now HtmlUnit(without Selenium), but im not satisfied with the speed, it is almost as slow as a Firefoxbrowser because of the slow Javascript rendering.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [ScriptEngine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html#method.summary) to evaluate a PhantomJS script inside Java; see [here](http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/04/05/java8-nashorn-tutorial/) for details. Example:

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
engine.eval(new FileReader("script.js"));
```

Comment: You can't do that. PhantomJS scripts are not self-contained, they depend on the PhantomJS API which is not present if you do just that. Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: You could try using PhantomJS [Inter Process Communication](http://phantomjs.org/inter-process-communication.html) or [phantomjs / javabindings](https://github.com/KDAB/phantomjs/tree/javabindings/javabindings).

Comment: Some kind of IPC is the easiest solution and is a valid answer. Although, the javabindings seems interesting. Could you write up an answer with sample code (how to use), maybe even how to build? You can add this to your existing answer, but can also post a separate answer.

Comment: This would be great +1!